# How to execute excel macro file in php excel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am developing a calculator program in which some calculation done by excel macro but i could not understand how i done macro calculation using PHP.
if anyone have a link or solution about that kindly help me! or referenced me how can i done this in server side.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). _"Questions **asking us to recommend or find** a book, tool, **software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: I seriously doubt that you can execute a Excel macro using PHP. Excel macros are using "Visual Basic for Applications" (VBA), which doubt that anyone have built a runtime for in PHP (it's most likely not even open source).